# Roslyn.. getting DescendantNodes

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer

I have a problem with roslyn method DescendantNodes()..With this line

```
var blockNodes = root.DescendantNodes(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.Block))
```

When I use lambda expression in this case in Debug mode it works..But when I build DLL and connect it to project as analyzer it dont work..It works only when I rewrite it to this:

```
var nodes = root.DescendantNodes();
var blockNodes = nodes.Where(n => n.IsKind(SyntaxKind.Block));
```

Where is the problem and how can i fix it ?

Comment: Could you provide more informations on your code? For example what is `root`?

Comment: SyntaxNode root = context.Tree.GetCompilationUnitRoot(context.CancellationToken); @nalka

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why debug mode works differently for you.  However, I think you may be using the method DescendantNodes incorrectly.

The function that is passed to DescendantNodes is a predicate that determines if the algorithm walking down the syntax tree finding descendants continues on to a given node's children or not. If this function returns false, then no additional children down that syntax tree path are returned.

This is very different than using the LINQ Where method, which filters the set to only nodes that match the predicate.

For example, the first one might find all the nested pure blocks in a method body, but not find any blocks that are parts of other kinds of statements, since those will never be considered because other kinds of statements are not themselves blocks. However, using the second form (Where method), the function considers all nodes under the root, and thus finds all blocks.